# Where to put the throws clause in a property declaration?

Tags: syntax, vala, checked-exceptions

The compiler complains about this code:

```
public OdbcVersion odbc_version { set { set_odbc_version_ (value); } }

private void set_odbc_version_ (OdbcVersion value) throws UnixOdbcError {
    if (!succeeded (set_environment_attribute_real (handle, Attribute.ODBC_VERSION, (void *) value, 0))) {
        throw new UnixOdbcError.SET_ENVIRONMENT_ATTRIBUTE ("Could not set environment attribute");
    }
}
```

The message is:

```
/mnt/code/dbdiadesign/src/unixodbc.vala:65.42-65.66: warning: unhandled error `UnixOdbc.UnixOdbcError'
```

Where do I put the `throws` clause in a property declaration?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can't throw errors in property getters or setters.

Comment: I'll just use a method instead of a property then. Is there any reason for this?

Comment: It's a carry over from the GLib-style C coding conventions.